# Django-Oscar 3.1.6 Frobshop NullBooleanField warning

Tags: django, django-oscar

Following the [Frobshop docs](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html), I installed `django-oscar` v3.0.0, which pulled in `django` v3.1.6.

Every time I run `manage.py` I get this warning:
`WARNINGS: catalogue.ProductAttributeValue.value_boolean: (fields.W903) NullBooleanField is deprecated. Support for it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in Django 4.0. HINT: Use BooleanField(null=True) instead.`

I grepped for `NullBooleanField` in the Frobshop source, but there were no results. Is there a way to either fix the problem or suppress the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search your Python environment folder where pip would have installed `django-oscar`, from there you need to find inside your environment this folder below:

```
.../lib/site-packages/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_model.py
```

In **abstract_model.py**, change line **1043** from:

> ```
> value_boolean = models.NullBooleanField(_('Boolean'), blank=True, db_index=True)
> ```

to

> ```
> value_boolean = models.BooleanField(_('Boolean'), blank=True, db_index=True)
> ```

You should see the warning disappear after you save the change.

Comment: It has been resolved in the official git repo of django-oscar, I guess a matter of time before the pip version is also rectified for the v3.0

Comment: Thanks for taking some of the mystery out of  `django-oscar`. I had installed it in WSL2, using a venv in `var/work/django/oscar/`. The directory was `/var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oscar/apps/catalogue`.

Comment: More info, with better formatting, here: https://www.mslinn.com/django/300-evaluating-django-oscar.html#warn

Comment: we're in may 2021, fix still didn't propagate to the PyPi =) Spent some time finding the file, but felt very dirty manually modifying it inside the virtualenv's packages; then found this answer, and my guess is that dirty hackery is indeed justified!